# Issue with garbage collection Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, ddms

I'm developing an app for tivi box powered by Android2.2. I have a loading screen and all of data have been downloaded. After data downloaded it change to home screen . My home screen layout has [image]

4 relative layouts are the same. [image]

When i move from gridview to ImageButtons and versa, alot of GC fire in logcat. So it's very slow when moving between items.

[image]

i tried to use allocation tracker and find it allocated a lot in text.staticLayout every time i move between items. When i remove 2 relativelayout in scrollview, GC still fire but the animation is less slow. So i think my problem is scrollview.
Can you show my how to find what cause alot of GC (guide to use allocation tracker more effectively. I read 2 articles on Romain Guy blog about DDMS and google I/O memory managerment for Android.)
[image]

My adapter is simple. I also try to remove all applyReflection, custom font so it's only getName from Item and set to TextView. But it still slow. applyReflection class from *[this tut](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/12/android-reflections-with-bitmaps.html)*

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Clip item = listClip.get(position);
    View itemView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem_home, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.filmIcon); 
        holder.genre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cliptype);
        holder.view = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.clipview);
        holder.name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.clipName);

        holder.view.setTypeface(myriadRegular);
        holder.name.setTypeface(myriadBold);
        holder.genre.setTypeface(myriadRegular);

        itemView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        itemView = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }

    holder.icon.setImageBitmap(Utils.applyReflection(bitmap));
    holder.name.setText(item.getName());
    holder.view.setText("Number of view: "+item.getNumberView());
    holder.genre.setText(item.getTypename());
    return itemView;

}

class ViewHolder {

    ImageView icon;
    TextView name, genre, view;
}
```

Thanks for your help. I'm new Android

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a GC bug in Android which I've found a workaround to get this garbage collected properly. Maybe this will apply to your situation as well.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488

Here's a drop-in solution. Just derive from BetterActivity instead of Activity. This will clean up all the drawables on orientation change, and likely on activity switches etc...

```
public abstract class BetterActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    System.gc();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    System.gc();
  }

  @Override
  public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
  {
    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup)
      LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutResID, null);

    setContentView(mainView);
  }

  @Override
  public void setContentView(View view)
  {
    super.setContentView(view);

    m_contentView = (ViewGroup)view;
  }

  @Override
  public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params)
  {
    super.setContentView(view, params);

    m_contentView = (ViewGroup)view;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Fixes android memory  issue 8488 :
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488
    nullViewDrawablesRecursive(m_contentView);

    m_contentView = null;
    System.gc();
  }

  private void nullViewDrawablesRecursive(View view)
  {
    if(view != null)
    {
      try
      {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;

        int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for(int index = 0; index < childCount; index++)
        {
          View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(index);
          nullViewDrawablesRecursive(child);
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {          
      }

      nullViewDrawable(view);
    }    
  }

  private void nullViewDrawable(View view)
  {
    try
    {
      view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {          
    }

    try
    {
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;
      imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
      imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {          
    }
  }

  // The top level content view.
  private ViewGroup m_contentView = null;
}
```

Comment: Do I just simple extend my current class from your betteractivity, dont i? And keep my current code in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
holder.icon.setImageBitmap(Utils.applyReflection(bitmap));
```

Utils.applyReflection is to create the bitmap or not?

if create, this method will block, and create bitmap will cause the gc in memory low.

Comment: ApplyReflection class from this tut :http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/12/android-reflections-with-bitmaps.html. My item has imagelink and i download it later(using ImageDownloader from GoogleTV: http://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/source/browse/src/com/example/tv/videoplayer/ImageDownloader.java?spec=svnc5ce73eef28e2b59891ce43af8fb668d5af0f85b&r=c5ce73eef28e2b59891ce43af8fb668d5af0f85b) and applyReflection. I tried remove bitmap so it's only getName from Item and set to TextView. But it's no help, it's still slow.